# golang google oauth2 - not able to get user info (library : https://github.com/golang/oauth2)

Tags: oauth, go, google-oauth, martini

i am using the following library for google oauth2 https://github.com/golang/oauth2

I am using the code given in the examples (url : http://play.golang.org/p/qXyuaVEhyS ,https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google )

I am able to get the auth code and token , but not able to make a get request to get user info

MyCode :

```
conf := &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     "my client id",
        ClientSecret: "secred id",
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:3000/googlelogin",
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        },
        Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
    }

m.Get("/googleloginrequest", func(r render.Render, request *http.Request) {

    url := conf.AuthCodeURL("state")
    fmt.Printf("Visit the URL for the auth dialog: %v", url)

    r.Redirect(url)

})

m.Get("/googlelogin", func(r render.Render, request *http.Request) {

        authcode := request.FormValue("code")

        tok, err := conf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, authcode)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext, tok)

        resp, err :=client.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me")

        r.JSON(200, map[string]interface{}{"status":resp})
    })
```

the response i get here is very big and does not have any user info

response :

```
 200 OK","StatusCode":200,"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Alternate-
Protocol":["443:quic,p=0.02"],"Cache-Control":["no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-
revalidate"],"Content-Type":["application/json; charset=UTF-8"],"Date":["Tue, 23 Dec 2014 18:18:19 
    GMT"],"Expires":["Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"],"Pragma":["no-cache"],"Server":["GSE"],"Vary":
    ["Origin","X-Origin"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-Frame-Options":["SAMEORIGIN"],"X-Xss-
    Protection":["1; mode=block"]},"Body":{},"ContentLength":-1,"TransferEncoding":
    ["chunked"],"Close":false,"Trailer":null,"Request":{"Method":"GET","URL":
 {"Scheme":"https","Opaque":"","User":null,"Host":"www.googleapis.com","Path":"/userinfo/v2/me","RawQuery
    ":"","Fragment":""},"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Authorization":["Bearer 
    ya29.5QDPWWRKB7tNkdB2Yvm0PCST9LF_iQhjN1Y0g2abE-
    lnw9BNgEd_n3A85ZfJzDNYZywqqElCb7Z2xA"]},"Body":null,"ContentLength":0,"TransferEncoding":null,"Close":fa
    lse,"Host":"www.googleapis.com","Form":null,"PostForm":null,"MultipartForm":null,"Trailer":null,"RemoteA
    ddr":"","RequestURI":"","TLS":null},"TLS":{"Version":771,"HandshakeComplete":true,"DidResume":false, 
    ....
```

Please help, or suggest me other working library/code ,which works in the above scenario

Comment: I got similar problem, btw that API will be deprecated in 20 April 2015..

Comment: Hi , I have a working code using another library .Please check the answer to this post . Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: thanks, I also have found the solution for my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620344

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this Library works for me "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"

Initiatialization

```
googleconf = &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     "your-client-id",
        ClientSecret: "youe-secred",
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:300/googlelogin",
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        },
        Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
    }
```

Redirect User on Request :

```
url := googleconf.AuthCodeURL("state")
response.Redirect(url)
```

Getting Data From Google :

```
    authcode := request.FormValue("code")

    tok, err := googleconf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, authcode)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err is", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("token is ", tok)
    response, err := http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=" + tok.AccessToken)

    defer response.Body.Close()
    contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
```

Comment: this is great. just what i need!